# adding route using app.use() inside eval() produces error, runs fine without eval()

Tags: node.js, express, eval

I have a class for adding routes to my API:

```
class RouterLoader{    
    constructor(app){
        this.app=app;
    }
    loadRoutes(){
        eval(`var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');`);
        eval(`this.app.use('/',indexRouter);`);
    }
}

module.exports = RouterLoader;
```

I am using `eval()` because I want to loop through all the files in `./routes`, adding each route using the same `require()...app.use()` (if there is a better way to add all routes, I'm open to suggestions).

Here is the `index.js` file I am using for this `app.use()`:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index.html');
});

module.exports = router;
```

And here is where I actually call `loadRoutes` in my `app.js` file:

```
const RouterLoader = require('./routerLoader');
const routerLoader = new RouterLoader(app);
routerLoader.loadRoutes();
```

This gives me the error:

```
this.app.use('/',indexRouter);
                 ^
ReferenceError: indexRouter is not defined
```

However, when I remove the `eval()` calls, like this:

```
    loadRoutes(){
        var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
        this.app.use('/',indexRouter);
    }
```

Then the code executes successfully and the REST endpoint is accessible as expected.

I thought it might be a scope issue, so I changed the `app.use()` to:

```
        eval(`this.app.use('/',this.indexRouter);`);
```

But then that gave me the error:

```
TypeError: Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a undefined
```

What's wrong with the way I am using `eval()` here?

Comment: Why does this need `eval` at all? Assuming you have an array of modules, just iterate over it and `this.app.use('/', require(module))` for each one.

Comment: @jonrsharpe,if each of the modules is defined as /routes/[modulename].js, how do I obtain an array of modules other than using `fs.readdirSync(route_directory)`, which would give me an array of strings that I would then need to use `eval()` to plug into `this.app.use('/',require(${modulename})`? also keep in mind that i need to use `this.app.use('/[modulename]')` to add a route, right?

Comment: Again, why would you need `eval` for that? `.use` and `require` both take strings, just _build the strings_.

Comment: @jonrsharpe thanks, that worked.  I had overlooked the possibility of calling `require(module)` inside the `app.use()` and thought I needed to create a constant with a unique name to pass into each `.use()`.